# Generic List to CSV String

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list that I want to write to a CSV string.

The examples I have found all seem to be for single item lists, mine has multiple items.

The code I currently have is;

```
private static string CreateCSVTextFile<T>(List<T> data, string seperator = ",") where T : ExcelReport, new()
{
  var objectType = typeof(T);
  var properties = objectType.GetProperties();
  var currentRow = 0;
  var returnString = "";
  foreach (var row in data)
  {
    var currentColumn = 0;
    var lineString = "";
    foreach (var info in properties)
    {
      lineString = lineString + info.GetValue(row, null) + seperator;
      currentColumn++;
    }
    if (seperator != "")
    {
      lineString = lineString.Substring(0, lineString.Count() - 2);
    }
    returnString = returnString + Environment.NewLine + lineString;
    currentRow++;
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

But when the list is large this method takes a very long time to run.

The class my list is based on looks like;

```
internal class ClientMasterFile
{
public String COL1{ get; set; }
public String COL2{ get; set; }
public String COL3{ get; set; }
public String COL4{ get; set; }
public String COL5{ get; set; }
public String COL6{ get; set; }
public String COL7{ get; set; }
public String COL8{ get; set; }
public String COL9{ get; set; }
public String COL10{ get; set; }
public String COL11{ get; set; }
public String COL12{ get; set; }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this using an advanced version of String.Join?

Thanks

Comment: You're using string concatenation. Use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Create a ToString() method override in your ClientMasterFile and you won't need Reflection because that's what takes so long there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your method can be simplified using [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) and [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join.aspx).

Concatenating strings directly is slow and uses a lot of memory which is fine for small operations.

See: [Does StringBuilder use more memory than String concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191079/does-stringbuilder-use-more-memory-than-string-concatenation)

```
private static string CreateCSVTextFile<T>(List<T> data, string seperator = ",")
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(row, null));
        var line = string.Join(seperator, values);
        result.AppendLine(line);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

A more complete implementation for CSVs:

```
private static string CreateCSVTextFile<T>(List<T> data)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(row, null))
                               .Select(v => StringToCSVCell(Convert.ToString(v)));
        var line = string.Join(",", values);
        result.AppendLine(line);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}

private static string StringToCSVCell(string str)
{
    bool mustQuote = (str.Contains(",") || str.Contains("\"") || str.Contains("\r") || str.Contains("\n"));
    if (mustQuote)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("\"");
        foreach (char nextChar in str)
        {
            sb.Append(nextChar);
            if (nextChar == '"')
                sb.Append("\"");
        }
        sb.Append("\"");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    return str;
}
```

Using: [escaping tricky string to CSV format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377454/escaping-tricky-string-to-csv-format)

Comment: You don't need the generic constraints either. I'm glad you found this helpful!

Answer (score 0):

we use linqtocsv with some success

https://linqtocsv.codeplex.com

and here is some explanation

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library