# How to read header information of XML file using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

Desired output

[image]

I am trying to read an xml doc using xpath. I am able to read the some elements but some not. I am trying to read this xml file and write this information in an excel file

I tried the following

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

 xmlDoc.Load("C:/Users/mypc/Documents/project/myfile.xml");
            XmlNode titleNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//header");
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/myuser/Documents/project/WriteLines.txt"))
            {
                if (titleNode != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText.ToString());
                outputFile.WriteLine(titleNode.InnerText);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

My xml file looks like this

```
<header version="2.0">
    <phone>1234567</phone>
    <houseNumber>45</houseNumber>
    <date>2015-09-19</date>
    <deliveryId>12345696015</deliveryId>
  </header>
```

Is there any way I can read the children and write it in excel file ?

Comment: It's still unclear to me what are you trying to achieve. Could you at least attach the desired output?

Comment: I just modified my post with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1 - iterating over child nodes

You've done pretty well finding the `<header>` element in the document using XPath. To extract information from individual child nodes just iterate over the `ChildNodes` collection using value of `LocalName` and `InnerText` properties of `XmlNode` for output like this:

```
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//header").ChildNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.LocalName + ", " + xmlNode.InnerText);
}
```

Note that `//header` XPath in combination with `SelectSingleNode` selects the first `<header>` element anywhere in the document. If the intent was to select the root node of the document then you should use `/header`, however selecting single root node isn't probably worth an XPath query.

### Part 2 - output to MS Excel

I'd recommend you to pick some [third party package](https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel) to produce output in specific format. If you just need simple export for further processing, the easiest way is to produce a CSV file, which you can easily open in MS Excel:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
var separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator;
var output = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//header").ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>()
    .Select(xmlNode => xmlNode.LocalName + separator + xmlNode.InnerText);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", output);
```

Please note that this is a very simple solution. Proper solution would include some [escaping of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377454/escaping-tricky-string-to-csv-format) on output.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you.. 
{

```
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();  
        dt.TableName = "Details";  
       dt.Columns.Add("phone", typeof(string));  
        dt.Columns.Add("houseNumber", typeof(string));  
         dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(string));  
        dt.Columns.Add("deliveryId", typeof(string)); 

        dt.Rows.Add("1234567", "45","2015-09-19","KV12_3896096015");  


       //Create Temp directory to save xml file  
        var tempDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());  
         Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);  
        string path = Path.Combine(tempDir, string.Format("{0}.{1}", "Prodcuts", "xml"));  
       //Write to xml file  
        dt.WriteXml(path, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);  

        //Create HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent  
        using (var client = new HttpClient())  
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())  
        using (var fromFile=File.OpenRead(path))  
        {  

            formData.Add(new StringContent("Test"), "FileName");  
            formData.Add(new StringContent("xlsx"), "FileFormat");  
            formData.Add(new StreamContent(fromFile), "DataFile",Path.GetFileName(path));  
            //Call WebAPI  
            var response = client.PostAsync(webapiURL, formData).Result;  
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid response.");  
                return;  
            }  
            var tempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());  
            if (!Directory.Exists(tempPath))  
            {  
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);  
            }  
            //Save Excel file to Temp directory
```

}